# Getting previous value in even after setter set javascript

Tags: javascript

I am just trying getter and setter methods In Java script
I write following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var Circle = function(radius) {
            this._radius = radius;
        }

        Circle.prototype = {
            set radious(radius) {
                this._radius = radius;
            },
            get radious() {
                return this._radius;
            },
            get area() {
                return (3.14 * (this._radius * this._radius));
            }
        };

        var circ = new Circle(10);

        circ.radius = 15;

        document.write("A circle with radius " + circ.radius + " Have an area of " + circ.area);
    </script>
```

So I got this output in browser

```
A circle with radius 15 Have an area of 314
```

here radius of circle is get updated but in area() its using old value.
Whats wrong in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss spelled `radius` in your setter. You typed `radious`. Other than that your code looks good.

Comment: :) :) :)  thanks its working

Comment: please consider accepting my answer with the check button :)

Comment: yes stack overflow say wait 9 min to accept answer :)